# Extjs - Populate combobox whit store not match

Tags: extjs

I need populate a combobox whit a store, all work fine except one thing. ¿Why the store populate only the **displayField** and not the **valueField**.

In this line

```
form.loadRecord(records[1]);
```

I set that record in the form, is fine but when i try submit the form i hope the value "2" and not the value "Media".

The code and the example on Jsfiddle for better explanation.

http://jsfiddle.net/jjgrn/5/

```
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['id', 'status'],

        data: [
                { id: '1', status: 'Baja' },
                { id: '2', status: 'Media' },
                { id: '3', status: 'Alta' },
                { id: '4', status: 'Urgente' }
        ]
    });

    var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        title: 'Edit Country',
        url: 'http://aaa.com/',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                fieldLabel: 'Nombre',
                name: 'status',
                anchor: '50%',                          
                displayField: 'status',            
                valueField: 'id',
                store: store
            }
        ],
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Guardar',
                handler: function () {
                    var form = formPanel.getForm();
                    var value = form.getValues();

                    alert(value.status);
                }
            }
        ],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });



    store.load({
        scope: this,
        callback: function(records, operation, success) {
            var form = formPanel.getForm();
            form.loadRecord(records[1]);
        }
    });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because form.loadRecord() doesn't do exactly what you're expecting it to do.
What you want it to do is to tell combobox to use that particual record (records[1]).
What it actually does is to tell combobox: "now set your value to Media", which combobox politely does though it's too "stupid" to associate it with particular record.

Here's the fixed version, not sure if such solution fits your needs:
http://jsfiddle.net/jjgrn/6/

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['id', 'status'],

    data: [
            { id: '1', status: 'Baja' },
            { id: '2', status: 'Media' },
            { id: '3', status: 'Alta' },
            { id: '4', status: 'Urgente' }
    ]
});

var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Edit Country',
    url: 'http://aaa.com/',
    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        fieldLabel: 'Nombre',
        name: 'status',
        anchor: '50%',                          
        displayField: 'status',            
        valueField: 'id',
        store: store
    }
    ],
    buttons: [
    {
        text: 'Guardar',
        handler: function () {
        var form = formPanel.getForm();
        var value = form.getValues();
        alert(value.status);
        }
    }
    ],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});



store.load({
    scope: this,
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
    // the operation object
    // contains all of the details of the load operation
    //var form = formPanel.getForm();
    //form.loadRecord(records[1]);
    formPanel.items.first().select(records[1]);
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what `ComboBox.select()`, `Form.loadRecord()` and `Form.getValues()` do. Your example still displays just the id. See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `form.getValues()`, you only get the value, if you want the associated record for a value, you have to search the store. http://jsfiddle.net/jjgrn/7/

```
    var rec = store.getById(value.status);                
    alert(rec.get('status'));
```

Key is understanding that `getValues()` just calls `getValue()` for each field in the form. `getValue` doesn't return a record, just the field from the record that you told it to use `valueField: 'id',`.